# numpy and matplotlib : Integration inside contour in a 2D plot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have a function : *z=f(x,y)* and I draw a contour plot.

For example :

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(0,10,11)
y=np.linspace(0,10,11)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=(X+4)*(X-14)*(Y+6)*(Y-14)/1000
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
CS= ax.contour(x,x,Z,[7],colors='black')
ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10)
```

From the contour path data points (`CS.collections[0].get_paths()[0]`), how is it possible to integrate *z* inside this area ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: This is a complete different question as your previous one, and also a lot more complicated. IIUC, you want to calculate an approximate volume given 121 xyz values and then limit it by some polygon?  Note that in general there can be multiple polygons with multiple holes. In any case, `contour` may help to visualize things but doesn't seem the correct approach for doing calculations.

Comment: @JohanC. My previous one ?

Comment: @JohanC; What is the correct approach ?

Comment: Could you confirm whether my assumptions about what you're trying to calculate were correct? And add a bit more background about what you're really trying to accomplish? How many points do you have? Is your function bumpy or rather flat?  A more correct approach would forget about `contour` (except for illustrating purposes) and look at scipy's 2D interpolation and integration functions. Also note that you probably only can obtain an extremely crude approximation of the integral.

Comment: @JohanC. The Z values are numerical measurements. Size is around100 x 100. Function is rather flat. I would like to integrate a volume under a surface (not necessarily a square) defined by z >= z0. A basic method would be to sum z*dx*dy when z=>Z0 but I am looking for something better. As in 1D integration (trapezoid, gaussian, spline ...) but in 2D with x,y values of the contour curve.

Comment: @JohanC. To do something less complicated. I plan to do a trapezoidal integration but in 2D. Points that are fully outside of the contour plot are not considered. Points that are fully inside of the contour plot are added (I suppose dx*dy=1) and for the remaining points, I have to calculate a "reduced" surface before multiplying by z. So I have two problems, how to know the category of points from contour coordinates and how can I calculate the coefficient.

Comment: Your "basic" method sounds right to me.  If you want more interpolation, then do a two-d interpolation first, and sum up over smaller dx*dy.  I wouldn't use the output from contour for this.

Comment: @jody Klymak. Do you know if such function exists in a library ?

Comment: If you just want isotropic interpolation: interp2d:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html Sometimes it also makes sense to just do 1-d interp on the columns, followed by the rows.